# Redirect to a dynamic page with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

This is what I am trying to do:

```
function show_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
if (r==true)
  {
  window.location = "delete.php?case=<?php echo $case; ?>";
  }
else
  {
  window.close() 
  }
}

<input type="image" src="images/delete.gif" name="image" onclick="show_confirm()">
```

But it redirects here:
http://localhost/delete.php?case=

When it should redirect here:
localhost/delete.php?case=$case

*could not edit previous post

Comment: what's the problem with what you have there?

Comment: Please! Don't let the user pass php code to be executed on the server.

Comment: not worried about malicious users its for an internal system. this works: window.location = "delete.php";. Stops working with PHP

Comment: What does that PHP evaluate to? I mean, what is in the HTML if you view source?

Comment: @Mike: if you can easily avoid such vulnerability, why not? About your problem, what does `alert("<?php echo $nt['id']; ?>");` show?

Comment: This should be right; is `$case` actually set at that point in the code? (Also, you probably don't want to use a GET request for this, if going to `delete.php` is actually deleting something)

Comment: Why did you repost the same question? Edit the other question found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777641/how-to-redirect-to-dynamic-url-in-javascript

Comment: It was a mistake. It would not let me edit the first question because I was posting 2 urls.. didn't realize this

Comment: @Mike - If you echo $case earlier on in your page, right after you assign its value, does it print anything?

Comment: It prints the value of $case, which is a number

Comment: And this assignment is above (in the same .php file) the <script> ... show_confirm() ... </script> part of your code?

Comment: @Mike: As Michael Mrozek mentioned, always a bad idea to have anything related to even the mere mention of 'delete' processed through what appears to be a GET request.  Spiders would greedily grab that url.  Regarding your actual question, you may have to post all code from where `$case` was assigned all the way down to where it's being used there.  Otherwise there's no telling from our perspective why it's current value is empty.  You'll also have to confirm if this is a .js file, and if so, confirm if that filetype is associated with php in your server.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer - Is it actually all that bad to use a GET request to delete something if, let's say, you're doing a $_SESSION-based user_id check on the delete.php page?  And with that in mind, what if this link only appears to logged in users who have permission to delete something?  Still a bad idea?  Is there any way for Spiders to get at that? (There could be something that I'm not considering, but I wanted to ask.  I didn't want Mike to have to worry about the GET issue if it's not actually much of a problem.)

Comment: @hithere: really that whole point about GET delete has nothing to do with OP's question.  Just a side-observation, really.  But on that topic, there's a story somewhere about a website or two losing a an entire table somewhere because of posted urls leading to delete scripts using GET parameters.  Consider if a user employs their own spider for say blog, website subscription updates, or message aggregation.

Comment: @hithere: also, I forgot about cross-site request forgeries.  Fun stuff when a user tries to load a seemingly harmless image and it empties their bank account.

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo $nt['id']; ?>`  is PHP.

```
location.href='delete.php?case='+case;
```

is better, assuming that your `case` variable has a value.

Answer (score 0):

You either generate the JavaScript dynamically or store the variable somewhere in your page where you can access with JavaScript (e.g. a hidden field).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want delete.php to be passed the value of `$nt['id']` or do you want the delete.php script to be passed the code `<?php echo $nt['id']; ?>`?
If you require the latter, you can do an eval on the value of `$_GET['case']` in delete.php:

```
eval( $_GET['case'] );
```

You'll have to remove the `<?php` and `?>` from the redirect for this to work. Keep in mind, this is very unsafe and I would highly suggest against it. In fact, you would be much safer specifying the name of the array (using variable variables) and a key value instead of code to execute.

```
$array = $$_GET['array'];
echo $array[$_GET['key']];
```

For more security, limit the variables that can be accessed so that a malicious user can't access any variable they wish.

```
if( !in_array( $_GET['array'], array('nt','otherArr','arr') ) {
    die( 'Nice try, my l33t enemy!' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` in the `onclick` event to stop the browser from processing the click on the link like this:

```
<input ... onclick="show_confirm(); return false">
```

OR

```
<input ... onclick="return show_confirm()">
```

and then change the return of `show_confirm()` to return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, the server must have PHP running. `<?php ?>` tags denote PHP code that runs on a server, not within the client.

What the browser needs to see in the source markup is:

```
window.location = "delete.php?case=1333"; // Or some such ID
```

For this to be the case, the server would replace the PHP code with the value found in the array by the id key name. For example:

```
<?php

$nt = array('id'=>1333);

echo "window.location = 'delete.php?case={$nt['id']}'";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe U can use it before it works you should download Jquery Library: [Download library](http://jquery.com/)

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$(':image').click( function(){      
    row_id= $(this).attr('row_id');
    show_confirm(row_id);                               
});

function show_confirm(row_id)
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
if (r==true)
  {
  window.location = "delete.php?case=" + row_id;
  }
else
  {
  window.close() 
  }
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="image" src="images/delete.gif" name="image" row_id='1'>
```

Hope it can help..

Answer (score 0):

Your $case should be know when PHP is create page, it looks like it unknown so why it empty...

When you create input element (with Image) - do you know your case ? If yes you can pass it as argument to show_confirm ( case )... and change part with:

window.location = "delete.php?case=<?php echo $case; ?>";

for

window.location = "delete.php?case=" + case;